# Is the sextic with duplicate roots solvable by differentiable Galois theory?

Tags: polynomials

*Differentiable* Galois theory addresses the solvability of the sextic polynomial equation with duplicate roots, even though it is correct that the general quintic is not solvable by radicals.
A polynomial with duplicate roots retains them under a linear transformation. Thus we can consider a sextic polynomial equation with duplicate roots with no 5th degree term. Differentiating the sextic polynomial by parts and equalizing to zero retains the duplicate root. This root may be a transcendental complex number, thus as a gcd the extended Euclidean algorithm may be inapplicable. Substituting the leading term of the quintic obtained by differentiation in the sextic term of degree 6 gives a solvable quartic for the duplicate root.
To solve the quartic use the method of Descartes in Joseph J. Rotman's *Galois Theory* which splits the quartic into the product of two quadratics. Alternatively, which may be new, solve
(x<sup>2</sup> + b)<sup>2</sup> + P(x + c)<sup>2</sup>
and compare these coefficients with
x<sup>4</sup> + ux<sup>2</sup> + vx + w.
 The result is a solvable cubic.
It is surprising that a sextic containing an unsolvable quintic is solvable. Its Galois group contains as a subgroup the Galois group of the quartic.
This seems to have an application to scheme theory where a variety with y<sup>2</sup> = 0 we have seen may have a galois connection but is treated differently from y = 0.

Comment: If we can determine the double root we can apply long division and immediately have the quartic we can solve.  Not sure what you mean by "Substituting the leading term of the quintic in the sextic"

Comment: A bit confused by the question - duplicate roots of polynomials in a single variable can be isolated as they are common roots of the polynomial and its derivative (in higher degrees there may be more than one duplicate root, and roots of orders greater than 2). The condition for a sextic to have a duplicate root is that the polynomial and its derivative have a common root. The fact that the general quintic, sextic etc are unsolvable by radicals does not mean that special cases are not. $x^6=0$ is a trivial example.

Comment: Differential Galois theory is a sort of Galois theory for *differential* equations. Why do you want to apply it to a *polynomial* equation?

Comment: If I guessed your intent correctly you are just describing the first step in calculating the gcd of the given polynomial and its derivative. That is a routine problem handled for example with Euclid's algorithm, so I don't understand exactly what you are asking. The absence of a 5th degree term doesn't really change the algorithm that much. Yes, in algebraic geometry intersection theory may lead to doubled points and such, but I still don't see a specific question.  Also what Another User said, this is not [differential Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_Galois_theory).

Answer (score 1):

$\def\ed{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
You don't need Galois theory, differential or otherwise, to find all the roots of any sextic with repeated roots.  You can always find all its roots by elementary means, as indicated by Mark Bennet in his comment.  If $\ r\ $ is a root of $\ g(x)\ $ of multiplicity $\ m\ $, then $\ g(x)=(x-r)^mh(x)\ $, where $\ h(r)\ne0\ $.  Therefore
\begin{align}
g'(x)&=m(x-r)^{m-1}h(x)+(x-r)^mh'(x)\\
&=(x-r)^{m-1}\big(mh(x)+(x-r)h'(x)\big)\\
&=(x-r)^{m-1}q(x)
\end{align}
where $\ q(x)\ed mh(x)+(x-r)h'(x)\ $, $\ q(r)=$$\,mh(r)\ne$$\,0\ $, and
$$
\gcd\big(g(x),g'(x)\big)=(x-r)^{m-1}\gcd\big((x-r)h(x),q(x)\big)\ .
$$
Since $\ x-r\ $ isn't a factor of $\ q(x)\ $ it can't be a factor of $\ \gcd\big((x-r)h(x),q(x)\big)\ $ either, and so $\ r\ $ is a root of $\ \gcd\big(g(x),g'(x)\big)\ $ of multiplicity $\ m-1\ $.  Thus, if
$$
q(x)=\prod_{i=1}^t\big(x-r_i\big)^{m_i}\prod_{j=t+1}^s(x-r_j)\ ,
$$
where $\ r_i\ne r_j\ $ for $\ i\ne j\ $ and $\ m_i\ge2\ $ for $\ i=1,2,\dots,t\ $, then
$$
\frac{q(x)}{\gcd\big(g(x),g'(x)\big)}=\prod_{i=1}^t\big(x-r_i\big)\ .
$$
Thus $\ \frac{q(x)}{\gcd\big(g(x),g'(x)\big)}\ $ is a polynomial whose roots are the repeated roots of $\ q(x)\ $, all of which are simple (i.e. of multiplicity $\ 1$). If $\ q(x)\ $ has degree $\ 6\ $ and at least one multiple root, then $\ \frac{q(x)}{\gcd\big(g(x),g'(x)\big)}\ $ has degree at most $\ 3\ $ (the maximum number of repeated roots that $\ q(x)\ $ can have).  You can therefore recover all the repeated roots of $\ q(x)\ $ by any of the known elementary methods for solving polynomial equations of degrees less than $\ 5\ $. Once you've found a repeated root $\ r\ $ you can easily find its multiplicity by repeatedly dividing $\ q(x)\ $ by $\ x-r\ $ until you get a non-zero remainder.  Once you've divided out the factor $\ \prod_\limits{i=1}^t\big(x-r_i\big)^{m_i}\ $ from $\ q(x)\ $, the quotient, $\ \prod_\limits{j=t+1}^s(x-r_j)\ $ will have degree at most $\ 4\ $, so you can also recover the remaining roots of $\ q(x)\ $ by elementary means.